# How can I make this grid variation of the voronoi diagram?

Tags: voronoi

I have a problem that reminds me of Voronoi, but I'm hoping that my variation will allow me to avoid using the Voronoi algorithm, and write something quicker.

Here's a horrible image I made in Paint to illustrate my problem:

[image: grid-like voronoi]

Say I have an area of a map.  Each dot represents a shop.  Each square represents a neighbourhood.  The voronoi diagram shows the areas closest to each shop.

If one of those areas dominates a square, then that whole square belongs to that shop.

Is it possible to determine which squares belong to which shop, without having to calculate an intermediate voronoi diagram?  It seems as though, since this is like a very rough approximation of a voronoi diagram, there should be a super fast shortcut to generating it.

Comment: I think defining which shop a neighborhood belongs to using the Voronoi diagram's area in each cell makes this harder to answer. Given your context, can you think of a way to phrase it that doesn't use features of the diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but can't you just find the vertex which is closest to the centroid of each square?

@user2615897 points out that this isn't generally correct (see comment).  None-the-less, I think it would be a ***good approximation*** for a grid which looks like your example (specifically: roughly equal-area cells, with spacings comparable to the square-sizes).

*My intuition is that without explicitly constructing the diagram, any approach will only be an approximation... but I'm not sure.*

This (segment) of a configuration illustrates the point:
The red vertex is nearest the center of the central square, while the green-vertex owns the most area.

[image]

Comment: It depends on the distribution of points. Imagine a single square, you could have a point in the center of the square, one point right above the center and one right below the center. The resulting Voronoi diagram will give the most space to the top most / bottom most point with the middle point having very little area.

Comment: I think an image of that example would be an great addition to this answer (as an instance when the approximation wouldn't work).

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix So long as I can force a situation where there's only one shop at most in each square, then this will work.  Thanks.  Also, this is one of those situations where the answer was so obvious that I facepalmed. :)

Comment: @KorganRivera Awesome!  Glad it'll work.  And yeah... that's definitely half of my SO questions.